# Android service not working on 5.1.1 version

Tags: java, android, service

I have a serious problem with **Service** on Android, specifically in version 5.1.1, well, I have an app that should run a service in the background all the time, I've done other app **before Android 5.0**, and **it always worked**, the problem is that In version 5.1.1 Service is not running when the user swipe it off from recent activity, it does not work.

I already researched a lot and can not find any solution, please help me.

**EDIT**:
My service (Firebase Cloud Messaging):

```
<service android:name=".service.FirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name=".service.FirebaseInstanceIdService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

My gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.thiengo.firebasenotification"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please provide stacktrace and code to help you find the problem.

Comment: Check it ou my code